# Problem with update/render in game loop (scrolling view, render interpolation)

Tags: 2d, game-loop, sfml, fixed-timestep, bug

I use SFML 2.2 and program a 2d prototype game (2d mario style where the camera follows the player).

I am experiencing the buggy imagery during rendering, for example a chunk of vertex array blocks are misplaced which gives an awful visual/glitches.

In other words:
the render does not match the expected state at the time at which the frame is presented to the user.

I've read several game-related articles regarding game loop, time step, etc and I *do* understand what's going on, but cannot spot the bug.

What I do: perform scene updates with fixed UPDATE_STEP value (it then gets used when calculating, for example, the Player's new position, being applied to the velocity, etc).
Then I use the remained slice of time since the last update divided by UPDATE_STEP as a ratio (0..1) to perform the interpolation during rendering.

Basically I change the position of my Player and calibrate the Camera accordingly, all the rest of the game scene (tile map represented as a vertex array) remains untouched.

Could you help me to figure out where's my mistake?
Here we go:

```
void gameLoop() {

    const sf::Time UPDATE_STEP = sf::seconds(1.0f / 120.0f);
    sf::Time timeSinceLastUpdate = sf::Time::Zero;
    _renderWindow.setFramerateLimit(60);
    sf::Clock clock;

    while (_renderWindow.isOpen()) {

        sf::Event event;
        while (_renderWindow.pollEvent(event)) {

            _curGameScene->processEvent(event);

            switch (event.type) {
            case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                switch (event.key.code) {
                case sf::Keyboard::Escape:                
                    _renderWindow.close();
                    break;                
                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                _renderWindow.close();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }

        _curGameScene->processKeyboard();

        sf::Time dt = clock.restart();
        timeSinceLastUpdate += dt;

        if (timeSinceLastUpdate > sf::seconds(0.25)) {
            timeSinceLastUpdate = sf::seconds(0.25);
        }

        while (timeSinceLastUpdate >= UPDATE_STEP) {

            _curGameScene->update(UPDATE_STEP.asSeconds());
            timeSinceLastUpdate -= UPDATE_STEP;
        }

        //RATIO FOR INTERPOLATION DURING RENDER
        const float alpha = timeSinceLastUpdate.asSeconds() / UPDATE_STEP.asSeconds();

        //normal draw
        _renderWindow.setView(_renderWindow.getDefaultView());
        _curGameScene->render(_renderWindow, sf::RenderStates::Default, alpha);

        //ortho draw
        _renderWindow.setView(_renderWindow.getDefaultView());
        _renderWindow.draw(infoText);
        _curGameScene->renderOrtho(_renderWindow);

        _renderWindow.display();
    }
}
```

my _curGameScene has the player sprite entity, the camera, which follows him, and the tile map (implemented as a vertex array).
so, in the update() method I do:

```
void LevelScene::update(float dtExpandedInSeconds) {
    _player->update(dtExpandedInSeconds);  
}
```

player's update method is as follows:

```
virtual void update(float dtExpandedInSeconds) {

    //store the previous position of the sprite
    _prevPos = _pos;

    //calculate the new position of the sprite
    _pos.x = _pos.x + _vxy.x*dtExpandedInSeconds;
}
```

then when we invoke the LevelScene's render method:

```
void LevelScene::render(sf::RenderTarget &target, sf::RenderStates renderStates, float ratio) {

    //CALCULATED POSITION OF THE CAMERA TAKING INTO ACCOUNT THE RENDER RATIO
    const sf::Vector2f viewCenter = _camera->calcPos(ratio);

    sf::View view = target.getView();
    view.setCenter(viewCenter);
    target.setView(view);
    target.clear(_bgColor);

    _tileMap->render(target, renderStates, ratio);
    _player->render(target, renderStates, ratio);
}
```

which involves the Camera's calcPos method:

```
const sf::Vector2f &calcPos(float ratio) {

    sf::Vector2f followPos = _sprite2Follow->getPos();
    sf::Vector2f followPrevPos = _sprite2Follow->getPrevPos();

    //HERE COMES THE INTERPOLATION
    _calcPos.x = followPrevPos.x*ratio + followPos.x*(1.0-ratio);
    _calcPos.y = followPrevPos.y*ratio + followPos.y*(1.0-ratio);

    if (_calcPos.x <= _halfViewWH.x) {
        _calcPos.x = 0;
    } else if (_calcPos.x <= _mapWH.x - _halfViewWH.x) {
        _calcPos.x = _calcPos.x - _halfViewWH.x;
    } else {
        _calcPos.x = _mapWH.x - _viewWH.x;
    }

    if (_calcPos.y <= _halfViewWH.y) {
        _calcPos.y = 0;
    } else if (_calcPos.y <= _mapWH.y - _halfViewWH.y) {
        _calcPos.y = _calcPos.y - _halfViewWH.y;
    } else {
        _calcPos.y = _mapWH.y - _viewWH.y;
    }

    _calcPos.x += _halfViewWH.x;
    _calcPos.y += _halfViewWH.y;

    return _calcPos;
}
```

The Player's render method:

```
virtual void render(sf::RenderTarget &target, sf::RenderStates renderStates, float ratio) {

    _sprite.setPosition(_prevPos.x*ratio + _pos.x*(1.0-ratio), _prevPos.y*ratio + _pos.y*(1.0-ratio));
    target.draw(_sprite, renderStates);
}
```

**UPDATED**:
I have a bit better results when I do not take the remained part of time slice into consideration and perform an additional update with that part, i.e.:

```
void gameLoop() {

    //... as above

    _curGameScene->processKeyboard();

    sf::Time dt = clock.restart();
    timeSinceLastUpdate += dt;

    if (timeSinceLastUpdate > sf::seconds(0.25)) {
        timeSinceLastUpdate = sf::seconds(0.25);
    }

    while (timeSinceLastUpdate >= UPDATE_STEP) {

        _curGameScene->update(UPDATE_STEP.asSeconds());
        timeSinceLastUpdate -= UPDATE_STEP;
        ++updatesCnt;
    }

    //ADDED 
    _curGameScene->update(timeSinceLastUpdate.asSeconds());
    timeSinceLastUpdate = sf::Time::Zero;

    _renderWindow.setView(_renderWindow.getDefaultView());
    _curGameScene->render(_renderWindow, sf::RenderStates::Default); //NO ALPHA IS PASSED
    //ortho draw
    _renderWindow.setView(_renderWindow.getDefaultView());
    _renderWindow.draw(infoText);
    _curGameScene->renderOrtho(_renderWindow);
    //
}
```

Player's update method now doesn't have the alpha value either, it sets the sprite image using just Player's _pos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have inverted the alpha in the interpolation.
It should be `curr*alpha + prev*(1-alpha)`.

From [Fix Your Timestep!](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/):

> `State state = currentState * alpha + 
>           previousState * ( 1.0 - alpha );`

In fact you are rendering an interpolated status that has 1 time-step of latency,
so

```
Actual time elapsed |----------|---_______|
Time simulated      |----------|__________|
Rendered time       |---_______|__________|
Render latency         |------- ---|
                       |  1-a  | a |

Legend:
- one tenth of time-step used
_ one tenth of time-step not used
| marks time-steps separation
```

Comment: yes, I already figured it out. I fixed the formula, but the glitches are still here, sadly.

Comment: Hmm. I do not completely understand the bad visual result you are experiencing. The player is correctly rendered always on center?

Comment: here's the video (taken on the smartphone): https://www.dropbox.com/s/w038trdfqm55gjl/buggy.mp4?dl=0 Here the bug is seen where green and yellow rectangles collide. Maybe that's a Nvidia tearing bug.

Comment: If you are referring to the fact that the screen seems to be divided in two parts, one part shifted, its clearly tearing. Try to enable v-sync and double buffering.

Comment: vsync is enabled in nvidia-settings, enabled in my SFML 2.2 app, as for double-buffering, it is, I believe, used internally in SFML lib. My guess it is an nvidia/ubuntu/maybe SFML fault. I still have the problem.

Comment: If you try to raise your target frame rate way over v-sync timing, and v-sync is really active, you should measure the ms per frame of the v-sync.

Comment: hmm, yes, I can get hundreds of FPS, no matter, whether v-sync is enabled or not. so, is that a bug, actually? the problem is that I have tearing even when I limit my SFML app to, say, 60 FPS programmatically.

Comment: Have you read this guide? http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/window-window.php#controlling-the-framerate pay attention to the red notes:

Sometimes setVerticalSyncEnabled will have no effect: this is most likely because vertical synchronization is forced to "off" in your graphics driver's settings. It should be set to "controlled by application" instead. 

Never use both setVerticalSyncEnabled and setFramerateLimit at the same time! They would badly mix and make things worse.

Comment: I partly fixed the bug. Now VSYNC gets applied on my PC (no tearing anymore), but still makes no difference on my notebook. Actually, the problem was with an internal implementation of setVerticalSyncEnabled method from the SFML 2.2 side: http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=17303.msg124897#msg124897 Now I want to understand how to enable VSYNC on my notebook. In nvidia-settings there's no "vsync" option to turn on/off, and setting vsync from SFML 2.2. makes no effect. Maybe it is somehow related to having two video cards on notebook.

Comment: as for SFML 2.2 bug I mentioned above, here it is: https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/issues/727 (I worked around that on PC, but the same approach doesn't work on my notebook, as I explained earlier).

Comment: Is possible that the workaround does not work because of multiple GPUs? Which GPUs do you have on the laptop?

Comment: probably, I don't know. I have GeForce GT 635M and an integrated Intel chipset "Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)".

Comment: The distro is the same? Try to discover which GPU is active. http://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system Install `mesa-utils` and run `glxinfo` in a terminal and look for the lines `server glx vendor string:` and `OpenGL version string:`

Comment: yes, the distro is the same. "server glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation"; "OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation"; "OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GT 635M/PCIe/SSE2".

Comment: I installed i915 intel driver and switched to intel. it works flawlessly, no more tearing/glitches, no matter whether or not I enable/disable vsync/limit FPS programmatically! Looks like it is where I'll finish my journey. Nvidia optimus technology leaves much to be desired, sadly. Thank you for the help! I award you :-)

Comment: Happy that you some how solved :)